# Is there a way for a Rust program to delete itself?

Tags: rust

I need a Rust program to delete itself after it has completed its purpose.

```
let output = Command::new("cmd")
        .args(&["/C", "delete.bat"])
        .output()
        .expect("Failed to execute command");
```

This is the code I use to run this bat file:

```
timeout 0.01
del nameofexe.exe
del delete.bat
```

It works fine on my computer but once I tried to run it on another machine it doesn't work.
It fails with an "access denied" error on the machine.

I tried the same approach with C++ and it worked.
Is there another way for the program to delete itself or is there a bug which I cannot see?

Comment: Windows does not allow you to delete a file while it is in use. Maybe the other machine you tested on is slower so you need a longer timeout?

Comment: i tried a longer timeout it's the same

Comment: you need to start your batch file in background maybe cmd /c start delete.bat to detach the program

Comment: So you start the batch from the program itself? Then it will always run no matter how long the timeout is.

You could use the batch to start the program and then delete it

nameofexe.bat:
`nameofexe.exe \n
del nameofexe.exe \n
del nameofexe.bat`

Comment: I am sure this is an example of a [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). What do you _really_ want to do? Why do you want to remove file with executable after it finishes running? Do you _think_ it is more secure?

Comment: i want the program to be able to delete himself after the end of the work

Comment: What is the use case for such a program?

Comment: it's an installer, it starts another file and deletes himself

Comment: Hello, please put answers in the answer box below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thi is the corrected code:

```
    let _output = Command::new("cmd")
    .args(&["/C ", path])
    .spawn()
    .unwrap();
```

You need to use `.spawn()` instead of `.output()`, because `.spawn()` detaches the process from the main program, instead `.output()` waits for the completion of the command.